# Python 3 - error handling in a GUI app

Tags: python, error-handling

So I'm making my first 'real' application but I want to know how to handle exceptions when I build my python script into an executable (`.exe`, Windows only). If I do normal `try`/`except` clauses, how should I record an error? I don't believe print functions would do anything, so does that just leave making some sort of log file?

Comment: If it's not a CLI, print statements to stdout and stderr aren't really applicable, so you're right in that you'd want to use [a logging mechanism](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html).

Comment: Thanks. I realize it seems like a rather simple question, but I really wasn't sure if I had any other options. Logs don't seem simple for most users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either it's a CLI application and you can use the print function (preferably using `stderr`). Or it's a window application and you can use some pop-up windows to announce the error to the user. Logs are of course applicable to both cases.

EDIT:

For pop-up in Windows you can use something like this:

```
import ctypes

ctypes.windll.user32.MessageBoxA(0, "Message", "Title", 1)
```